# Interface with Lotus Notes via COM in Golang

Tags: go, com, lotus-notes

I am trying to access the COM classes provided by the Lotus Notes client. In Python this has been quite easy with the `win32com.client` lib:

```
def initialize_notes(self):
    """
    Initializes an object from the class.
    :return: Lotus Notes database
    """
    notes_session = win32com.client.Dispatch('Lotus.NotesSession')
    notes_session.Initialize(self.notes_password)
    notes_database = notes_session.GetDatabase(self.domino_server, self.domino_db)
    return notes_database
```

Now in Go, I have been unsuccessful. Below is my code:

```
import (
    "github.com/go-ole/go-ole"
    "github.com/go-ole/go-ole/oleutil"
)

func Connect(dominoServer, database, notesPassword string) (*ole.IDispatch, error) {
    ole.CoInitialize(0)
    unknown, err := oleutil.CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    notes, err := unknown.QueryInterface(ole.IID_IDispatch)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    session := oleutil.MustCallMethod(notes, "Initialize", notesPassword).ToIDispatch()
    db := oleutil.MustCallMethod(session, "GetDatabase", dominoServer, database).ToIDispatch()
    return db, nil
}
```

Which panics with the following error `panic: Class not registered`. The class is registered though, as both the Powershell and Python version of the function can access it without a problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which operation causes the panic?

Comment: @captncraig well, I cause the panic at the first `panic(err)`, because I cannot load the class

Comment: CreateObject is a utility that looks up the ClassID via specific registry keys. See comment in [the relevant code](https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole/blob/8a4f5c214bfb4475619b8bb7ccbe6fa5c91745f4/com.go#L105) I'm guessing it is not registered, and the python lib is doing something slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

If Go is executing in a 64 bit environment and Powershell and Python are executing in a 32 bit environment - or vice versa, that's your problem. Note that the Lotus COM classes are [unsupported in 64 bit environments](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454291&cm_mc_uid=95993071871514306054987&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1506107594). They can be made to work (mostly) if you get them registered correctly, but a few of the calls do fail. If memory serves me correctly, all the methods that return collections of design elements fail, and there may be a few others.

Comment: I am aware that they are 32bit. When I use powershell I simply use the x86 version of it, but with Python I did no such thing. I compliled the programm in Go 32bit architectures, but it it still not working.